# Add data to non empty delimited file Talend

Tags: csv, talend

I'm trying to add rows to an existing file in Talend Open Studio that already contains rows. The problem is that everytime I try to add new Rows, the job deletes the content of the csv files to replace it with the new rows.

**Ex :**

**1st load :** 500 lines in source --> 500 new lines in my .csv file. **result :** 500 lines in the target file.

**2nd load :** 30 lines in source --> 30 new lines in my .csv file.  **result :** 30 lines in the target file, but it is supposed to be at the end of the file, and to have 530 lines.

Do you know how to do it ? Is there a way to specify the fact that I don't want to overwrite the target file ?

Am I supposed to get the data from the csv file, merge it with the new rows with a tUnite and put it in the destination file again ? (this way, the data would be overwritten with the data it contained).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in tFileOutput* component have setting called Append. if you check this option in component it will append to existing file and not overwrite it.